# Display static items according to page accessed, in PHP

Tags: php

I need to include some js, css type items in specific pages.

So far I've done the following:

```
define("DIR_ADMIN", "admin");

function fusion($location, $page, $type) {
    $dirAdmin = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIR_ADMIN;  
    $change = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $location);
    $changed = ucfirst($change);
    $result = $dirAdmin.$changed;

    if($type=='js'){
      echo "<script src='$result'></script>\n";
    } elseif($type=='css'){
      echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$result' />";
    } elseif($type=='favicon'){
      echo "<link rel='shortcut icon' href='$result' />";
    } elseif($type=='logo'){
      echo "<img src='$result' alt='logo'>";
    } else {
      echo $result;
    }
  }
```

In HTML I called the function like this:

```
<?php fusion("/assets/vendors/js/vendor.bundle.base.js", "clients", "js"); ?>
```

First is the file URL, then the page, and finally the file type.

What I'm not able to come up with is the part that receives the value `$page`.

I created a routing system in php, so all files are accessed like this: **index.php?page=clients**, except in the case of the homepage which is just **index.php**.

I need that when the value of `$page` is set for example with **clients** it should load all items that have this same when the **clients** route is accessed.

In some cases the route may have another word attached, for example: **index.php?page=clients-add**, in which case it should check if there is only the word **clients** in `$_GET`.

And if I set the value of `$page` to **all**, it should display on all pages. How can I do this?

Comment: I dont think you can just echo scripts like that. where is the html file code? you may need to run the conditions there instead of the controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your fusion function you need to pick up which page you're on and then including the displaying of content after that.

Use this snippet to help dictate the page you're on.

```
$curr_page = "home";
if ( isset( $_GET["page"] ) ) {
    $curr_page = $_GET["page"];
}

if ( $page == "all" || $page == $curr_page ) {
    //echo items here
}
```